# In Avkit how it can be used this three lines of codes, and also how to mute the music"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, media-player, avkit

In `AVKit` how it can be used this three lines of codes and also how to mute the music ?

```
moviePlayer!.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill

moviePlayer!.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None

moviePlayer!.shouldAutoplay = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using AVFoundation to mute audio playback using .muted on your AVPlayer. 
See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1716/_index.html